# Getting C++ library to work on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, c++, libraries

I'm trying to make [this pokerstove library](https://github.com/andrewprock/pokerstove#building)  to work so it could be `include`d and used in a simple .cpp file opened by simple text editor and compiled in terminal using

> g++ -o my_prog my_cpp.cpp

Instruction tells that I need the following installed on my platform of choice:

- boost, version 1.46 or higher
- cmake, version 2.4 or higher
- subversion, version 1.7 or higher

I did it using

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev cmake subversion
```

Also installed GNU C++ compiler like this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential
gcc -v
make -v
```

and git using

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

When i runed all the commands i was at my home folder (it's probably important)

```
girts@girts-ThinkPad-E520:~$
```

So far so good

---

Next i followed instructions

> To build under linux using cmake, create a build directory, invoke
>   cmake on the programs directory, then build.
>   So again from the same directory i runed all the commands

```
git clone https://github.com/andrewprock/pokerstove.git
mkdir pokerstove/src/build
cd pokerstove/src/build
cmake ..
make
```

Next the creator of the library says

> You should then be able to execute the simple command line example:

```
~/cmake/programs$ ./programs/ps-eval/ps-eval
```

So i runed it from here like this

```
girts@girts-ThinkPad-E520:~/pokerstove/src/build$ ~/cmake/programs$ ./programs/ps-eval/ps-eval
```

After it I got this error that there is no such directory which there isn't but is there anything I actually did wrong?

```
bash: /home/girts/cmake/programs$: No such file or directory
```

---

I tested out if those boost libraries were working with a simple code and everything were working fine. Anyway in the end i should be able to for example `include` there lines in my .cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/binomial.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <pokerstove/util/combinations.h>
#include <pokerstove/peval/Card.h>
```

As you can see this part is very interesting `<pokerstove/peval/Card.h>`

Would really appreciate if you guys would help me get it working. Maybe i somehow have to install everything in different place?

Comment: `~/cmake/programs$` isn't part of the command (it's just meant to represent the terminal prompt). Also the executable appears to be created in `./bin` not `./programs/ps-eval/` i.e. just type `./bin/ps-eval` from the `build` directory (from where you ran `make`).

Comment: @steeldriver I was three minutes slower = \

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ok:

```
git clone https://github.com/andrewprock/pokerstove.git
mkdir pokerstove/src/build
cd pokerstove/src/build
cmake ..
make
```

After that, the binaries will be in:

```
~/pokerstove/src/build/bin
```

Run the binary with:

```
~/pokerstove/src/build/bin/ps-eval
```

Comment: @etrusks Final version :)

Comment: Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) I just come to update the post because on other forum 1 guy also told me this and i actually was getting the same result as in the example
https://github.com/andrewprock/pokerstove#linux
But than i tryed to include these libraries in my .cpp file that i created inside my 
girts@girts-ThinkPad-E520:~/pokerstove/src/build$
directory and i was getting compiler error when i tryed to compile.
Could you maybe also know why did i get error that there is no such file and directory when i tryed to compile and compiler tryed to
incld<pokerstove/util/combinations.h>

Comment: @etrusks In order to avoid confusion here you should ask a new question. =)

Comment: @etrusks He, you have 15 reputations ;) Give me an upvote.