# Unable to use included library -> pokerstove in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, libraries

guys! I just included [this pokerstove library](https://github.com/andrewprock/pokerstove#pokerstove) with help of [good instructions](https://github.com/andrewprock/pokerstove#building) and with help of [this website and its users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614782/getting-c-library-to-work-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I ran all commands in my home directory which is

> girts@girts-ThinkPad-E520:~$

And the commands were these after installing all necessary tools

```
git clone https://github.com/andrewprock/pokerstove.git
mkdir pokerstove/src/build
cd pokerstove/src/build
cmake ..
make
```

As you see I ended up in this directory

> girts@girts-ThinkPad-E520:~/pokerstove/src/build$

and I did successfully run the command the creator of this library suggested to run which was

> girts@girts-ThinkPad-E520:~/pokerstove/src/build$ bin/ps-eval

Before I also installed boost libraries and tested that they work great
Now however I tried compile this simple ggg.cpp file that includes also these new pokerstove libraries
Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/binomial.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <pokerstove/util/combinations.h>
#include <pokerstove/peval/Card.h>

int main(){

    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

When i tryed to compile using

> girts@girts-ThinkPad-E520:~/pokerstove/src/build$ g++ -o programma
>   ggg.cpp

compiler gave me this error

```
ggg.cpp:8:42: fatal error: pokerstove/util/combinations.h: No such
file or directory  #include <pokerstove/util/combinations.h>
                                          ^ compilation terminated.
```

Is there anything I have done wrong? (Of course there is otherwise there wouldn't be this problem) Maybe installed it in some place where I shouldn't or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the path for the include files:

```bash
$ g++ -o programma ggg.cpp -I/home/<your_username>/pokerstove/src/lib
$ ./programma 
Hello World!
```

`-I<path_to_pokersove_headers>` - To specify a directory to search for header files

E.G.:

```bash
    $ find -name combinations.h
    ./pokerstove/src/lib/pokerstove/util/combinations.h
```

therefore use a relative path: `./pokerstove/src/lib/`
 or an absolute path: `/home/<your_username>/pokerstove/src/lib/`

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer!! I just tryed exactly like you said but still got the same error. Do i really just need to type this 
girts@girts-ThinkPad-E520:~/pokerstove/src/build$ g++ -o programma ggg.cpp -I~/pokerstove/src/lib

if my ggg.cpp file is in girts@girts-ThinkPad-E520:~/pokerstove/src/build$ ?
Or with -I~ you meant something else?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: I still dont really understand 
Tryed to compile it like this
girts@girts-ThinkPad-E520:~/pokerstove/src/build$ g++ -o programma ggg.cpp -I~/pokerstove/src/lib
but it didnt work.
Directory is right one - > I mean its in home folder than pokerstove/src/lib  -> and there is  pokerstove/util/combinations.h
Im sorry man im not that good with this yet

Comment: Tryed to build it like this
girts@girts-ThinkPad-E520:~/pokerstove/src/build$ g++ -o programma ggg.cpp -I<./pokerstove/src/lib/>
but it didnt work =/

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Use the complete path.

Comment: `g++ -o programma ggg.cpp -I/home/girts/pokerstove/src/lib`

Comment: Dude u have no idea how happy u made me feel. I have been trying to do this also on windows and without results. Thanks you soooooooo much :)))
Worked !!!!! :)